# How to fix "Specified cast is not valid" error in a thraed that using HtmlElementsCollection?

Tags: c#

I wrote code to automatically log in and log out in a website.
In the following code I wrote an event to log out and added it to a button click event to manually log out.
I also called it in another function to automatically log out after 10 seconds using `Task.Delay()`.

```
private void btn_logout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Navigated -= webBrowser1_Navigated;
    HtmlElementCollection elemcol = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");
    foreach (HtmlElement elem in elemcol)
    {
        string s = elem.InnerText;
        if (s != null)
            if (s.Equals(" Log out "))
                elem.InvokeMember("click");
    }
}
```

The problem is when I run the code, the event is automatically called, but in the line that "a" html tags were collected from the whole html document the "Specified cast is not valid" occurred.

After I continue running when I click on the related button the event is running and doing just fine.

In these two, the events were called, but I don't understand why the error occurred, when the execution has arrived to the line that I mentioned before and in the other way the error is not occurred.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: which line shows the error?

Comment: As you are using multithreading, the obvious guess is that the data is not ready for processing when you start this. Simple as that. Also you really need to work to get full debugging information. The message alone tells us nothing. Here two articles on proper exception handling: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/ | https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET

Comment: @Christopher yeah I guessed that. the 10 sec is a long time for waiting to load. besides I used the log out button before the delay time passed and it worked just fine.

Comment: HtmlElementCollection elemcol = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a"); @sujithkarivelil